# String rearragement

Tags: list-manipulation

I have another malformed list of football scores.  Each score is reported in one of seven(!) possible formats, each which is sampled below:

```
lis = {{"Findlay", "FIN 45", " Lake Erie", "3"},
       {"Emporia State", "EMP 38", "0", " Northeastern State"},
       {"10", " Lincoln (MO)", "Washburn", "WASH 24"},
       {"SROS 27", " Sul Ross State", "Wayland Baptist", "7"},
       {" Washington & Jefferson","Westminster (PA)","WJC 48","3"}
       {" Alfred State College", "13", "Husson", "HUS 31"},
       {" Gallaudet", "10", "UNE 31", "University of New England"}}
```

As can be seen, each record contains an all-caps abbreviation of one of the teams involved, which may (or may not) be the first 3 or 4 letters of the school's full name.

The goal is to rearrange the list to give:

```
res = {{"Findlay","45","Lake Erie","3"}, 
       {"Emporia State","38","Northeastern State","0"}, 
       {"Lincoln (MO)","10","Washburn","24"}, 
       {"Sul Ross State","27","Wayland Baptist","7"}
       {"Washington & Jefferson","48","Westminster (PA)","3"}
       {"Alfred State College","13","Husson","31"}
       {"Gallaudet","10","University of New England","31"}}
```

Thanks for suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, the answer I provided for your previous question also solves this one. (Note: as before you have missing commas in your data, which needs to be corrected before any of the solutions will work.)

```
Riffle @@@ 
  KeyValueMap[
    If[#1, Flatten[StringCases[#2, NumberString]], StringTrim[#2]] &] /@
      KeySort /@ (GroupBy[#, StringContainsQ[NumberString]] & /@ lis)
```

Unless you can explain the difference, this question should probably be deleted as a duplicate.

Comment: Yes you are right.  Thanks.  I tried to delete this question but it already has your response.